# multiply every number in a list by a number

Tags: list, function, haskell

I'm new to haskell and I'm trying to make a function that will multiply an int by every element of a list.

Example:

```
mult 2 [2,4,6]
```

Returns:

```
[4,8,12]
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Break the problem down into conceptual steps:

- You want to do something to every element of a list, which is a general operation provided by the `map` function. Using that, you can ignore the list, and consider only what you need to do with a single element.
- You want to multiply two numbers together. In any single use of the function, one of those numbers will be constant, so we can give it a name as an argument to the function: `mult x = ...`. Now we can treat `x` as a constant and only worry about the other number.
- The other number is not constant, so you need a function, not just a simple expression. Haskell provides "operator sections" to do this with infix operators like `(*)`, so using `x` we get `(x *)`.
- Backing out the last few steps, you're now giving `x` a name, and creating a function, which you pass to `map`

```
mult x = map (x *)
```

...and you're actually done at this point, if you want to be. But it might be clearer for a beginner to make the list an explicit argument:

```
mult x ys = map (x *) ys
```

Both forms do the same thing, though.

Answer (score 9):

I initially answered this with a somewhat dismissive golfy style, so let's try again.  My intention is twofold: to redeem myself for writing an uppity sleep deprived answer to a newcomer, :-), and to try to hint at the point free style:

```
mult_l = map . (*)
```

What does that code do?

It's helpful to think of it in a pipelined way:

- That code takes `(*)` and *feeds it in* to `map`.
- What is the type of `(*)`?  Well, it's `Num a => a -> a -> a`.  This means it does *what*?  Takes in a number (call it `x`), and gives you another function, this function will -- if given another number (call it `y`) -- compute `x` "times" `y`.  (I put "times" in parenthesis because `Num` is a typeclass...)
- Now you're going to *compose* `(*)` with `map`.  What does `map` do?  Well, let's look at its type: `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`.  So now, `map` takes a function as an argument and applies that function to each member of the list.

Now think about how composition works: `(f . g) x = f (g x)`.

If given an argument, say 2:

```
mult_l 2
```

is really

```
(map . (*)) 2
```

which is *really* just:

```
map (* 2)
```

Now, `map` takes two arguments, it takes a function (which says "what do you want me to do?") and it takes a list (which says "to what do you want me to do it?").  `map` then takes each of the items in that list, and applies the function to the elements, point wise.

This means that if you take something like:

```
map (* 2) [1,2,3]
```

Then map will take the list, and look at the first element, then multiply it by two, look at the second element, etc...

So the *type* of `map . (*)` is `Num a => a -> [a] -> [a]`, because it *takes in* a number `x`, and then feeds the higher order function `\x -> (* x)` on to `map`.

Now the challenge question for you (since you're new at Haskell), is how to write `map`?  I'll give you a hint:

- If you want to map a function over the empty list, then you return the empty list.
- If you want to map a function over a list *head*, together with its tail, you take the head, apply the function to the head, and then do the same thing to the rest of the list.

Out of this you get a recursive definition of `map`, along with an associated induction principle.

One other thing you might puzzle over is: why did I have to write `map . (*)` rather than just `map (*)`.  If you think about this for a while, you might become slightly more enlightened as to the [point free style](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree)

Comment: Indeed, the pro-golfers would write `map . (*)` and be done with it. Getting to that point takes a bit of sophistication, so thanks to C.A.McCann for documenting most of the journey.

Answer (score 8):

Since no body talked about list comprehensions, so just to tell about another way of doing it.

```
mult x ys = [i*x | i <- ys]
```

Comment: Purely for my interest, why the downvote..?  I agree it doesn't explain things the same way, and might be out of context for a beginner, but @Satvik doesn't claim it to be and this is a good alternative

Comment: @KristopherMicinski I prefer map over list comprehensions myself. I was just suggesting that there are other ways of doing it and you can choose whatever you like.

Comment: I understand that, my question still stands, while it's not the "canonical" way for me either, I don't think it warrants a downvote, it's not an inherently bad way to do it and demonstrating another purpose is instructive.